# Is it possible to create an UNIQUE KEY using only the date from a datetime column as one of the parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unique

This is the query I am trying to execute but it doesn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE values ADD UNIQUE(id_cod, id_op, (SELECT date(V.completed_date) FROM values V;));
```

I have these 3 columns in the values table: `id_cod`, `id_op` and `completed_date` which I want to use for the `UNIQUE KEY` but it is vital to me that I only use the date part of the date-time.

Answer (score 4):

You have three alternatives, none of which are great options.

The first is to include a separate column just for the date.  You can maintain this using a trigger, and then create a unique index using that column.

You can split the column into two pieces, a date and a time.  Then use only the date part for the index.

You can represent the field as a string, using the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  Then you can use a prefix index on this field:  `create unique index idx_values_3 on values(id_code, id_op, datestr(10))`.

I think the second option would be the most reasonable.

Comment: I agree that the second option is best. I don't agree though that it's not a great option :-) It seems that id_code + id_op + date build the table's natural key, whereas the time is just an additional information. So it makes complete sense to separate the two.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . Other databases support either function-based indexes or indexes on computed columns.  Those are better ways to implement such a unique index.

Comment: Yes I know of them and I agree when talking of an index that is meant to speed up access. Here, however, we are talking about a unique index. id_code + id_op + date uniquely identify a record. I think it's good to separate such a key from additional data.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in MySQL.

You can add a fourth column `completed_date_d DATE`, include it into the unique constraint and make a trigger which would update the column with date part of `completed_date`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It is useful to me.